# How to integrate facebook log in with codigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Experts, In my site users has normal log in and log in with face book and twitter, want to log in with face book and retrieve all user details from to insert in my site db.For this i had created API key and Application key using developers in my FB account,here is the problem is it successfully log in with face book, but i can't get the log in details of user. I hope you all will give a good solution for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this library

http://www.haughin.com/2009/05/18/new-codeigniter-library-facebook-connect/

Comment: na , me had done using the given link,but a problem is there, face book connect url is in my index page, when i click it, it redirect to log in page, but i cant get the details of the user, also can't log out the face book without using the original face book account